# About get the values from SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

I wanna set a `textview` as the values from `SQLite` when I click the `ListView`
Here is my way:

```
myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() { 
public void onItemClick(AdapterView arg0, 
android.view.View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) { 
myCursor.moveToPosition(arg2); 
setContentView(R.layout.main2); 
_id = myCursor.getInt(0); 
textStudyUID.setText(myCursor.getString(0));
```

But there is a exception, here is the log:

```
07-05 12:37:16.613: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(17689): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-05 12:37:16.613: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(17689): at irdc.sqlitetest2.SQLiteTest2$1.onItemClick(SQLiteTest2.java:53)
07-05 12:37:16.613: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(17689): at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
07-05 12:37:16.613: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(17689): at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3285)
07-05 12:37:16.613: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(17689): at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1640)
07-05 12:37:16.613: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(17689): at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
07-05 12:37:16.613: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(17689): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-05 12:37:16.613: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(17689): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-05 12:37:16.613: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(17689): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
07-05 12:37:16.613: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(17689): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-05 12:37:16.613: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(17689): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)

07-05 12:37:16.613: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(17689): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)

07-05 12:37:16.613: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(17689): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
07-05 12:37:16.613: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(17689): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is the full code:

```
public class SQLiteTest2<View> extends Activity {       
    private DoDB ToDoDB;
    private Cursor myCursor;
    private int _id;
    private ListView myListView;
    public TextView textStudyUID;
    protected ListAdapter adapter1;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);   
        myListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListView);
        textStudyUID = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.widget40);
        ToDoDB = new DoDB(this);
        myCursor = ToDoDB.select();
        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter1 = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.list,myCursor,new String[]{DoDB._StudyUID},new int[]{R.id.listTextView1});
        myListView.setAdapter(adapter1);

        myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0,android.view.View arg1, int arg2,                                     long arg3) {
               myCursor.moveToPosition(arg2);
               setContentView(R.layout.main2);
               _id = myCursor.getInt(9);
               textStudyUID.setText(myCursor.getString(0));
        }
      });
```

Comment: How is myCursor populated, and is it made `final` outside the `OnItemClickListener`?

Comment: Please format your code using the `101010`-button above the text edit field.

Comment: I've already populated myCursor like this "private Cursor myCursor" outside.

Comment: Your code looks fine, you need to step through the debugger and see which line causes the Null Pointer Exception.

Comment: Could you post the code where you are populating the cursor?

Answer (score 0):

You'll not be able to access myCursor inside the anonymous function (`onItemClick`) due to scoping, but the cursor you're after is already being passed to the function. Retrieve it using:

```
CursorAdapter adapter = (CursorAdapter) arg0.getAdapter();
Cursor myCursor = adapter.getCursor();
```

You may want to consider naming the parameters correctly to improve readability. I.e.:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<? extends Adapter> parent, View v, int position, long id)
```

Comment: I use "private final Cursor myCursor" but it says needed "="

Comment: Apologies, the first answer was wrong but I've updated with the correct method.

Comment: I've changed like this:
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<? extends Adapter> parent,
android.view.View arg1, int position, long id) {
CursorAdapter adapter = (CursorAdapter) parent.getAdapter(); 
Cursor myCursor = adapter.getCursor(); 
myCursor.moveToPosition(position);
setContentView(R.layout.main2);
_id = myCursor.getInt(9);
textStudyUID.setText(myCursor.getString(0));

Comment: Still this "java.lang.NullPointerException"

Comment: Can you paste the second line (the one after NullPointerException), it should give you the line number of the code which is causing the exception. And then open up SQLiteTest2, find the line mentioned and paste it here